# Control of battery charging

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, control, bridge-rectifier, alternator

I have been developing a control software for charging and discharging battery in a dc grid. The system consists of:

01) Three phase alternator with three phase diode bridge rectifier at its output and field current controller (nominal power of the alternator is \$P_{an}\$)

02) Load with variable power consumption (current power consumption of the load is \$P_l\$)

03) Bidirectional battery charger which works as a current source during charging and as a voltage source during discharging.

04) Li-Ion battery (power which is being currently charged or discharged is \$P_{bat}\$)

[image]

The main goals of the control software are:

01) determine the charging current of the battery and send this value into the battery charger

02) determine the output voltage of the battery charger during discharging and send this value into the battery charger

What I have been strugling with is how to determine the charging current and discharging voltage in a situation when I measure only the \$V_{veh\_bat}\$ and \$V_{dc\_bus}\$.

I have started with implementing a PID controller of the \$V_{dc\_bus}\$. This controller produces value of \$I_{charger}\$ at its output. In case \$I_{charger}>0\$ charging of the Li-Ion battery is requested and in case \$I_{charger}<0\$ discharging of the Li-Ion battery is requested. For discharging I am sending the reference \$V_{dc\_bus}\$ value as the discharging voltage for the battery charger.

This idea works only in case I don't allow \$I_{charger}<0\$ at the PID controller output i.e. only for charging. However the functionality is little bit doubtable because of the fact that the current for charging of the Li-Ion is drawn from the vehicle battery (which is being discharged due to this fact).

Does anybody have any suggestion how to solve it? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Maybe for Idc_bus if you know transfer function with load regulation, but not Ichg

Comment: Does the charger perform DC-DC?

Comment: Yes, the charger is a bidirectional dc-dc converter.